# Can the tab menu in the service cloud be horizontal and customize with CSS

Tags: custom-object, css, service-cloud-console, customization

Can the tab menu in the service cloud be horizontal and customize with CSS

[image: Can the tab menu in the service cloud be horizontal and customize with CSS]

Answer (score 0):

Hello i'm not sure do you still need it or not.
But here is some images. [image]

[image]